# How to fix a display issue with a website on iPad for iOS 17?

Tags: ios, ipad, web-testing, ios17

Long time lurker, first time asker. Hopefully someone can help out.

I work for a telecommunications company, and our direct sales team uses iPads and goes to our website to sign a customer up for service. As of yesterday, we were getting reports of our website not displaying correctly, leading to the team being unable to continue orders.

I wasn't able to replicate the issue - until I upgraded my own iPad to iOS 17. After that, I got the issue of overlapping text (which is what they were seeing).

The issues occurs in all browsers.

Did the usual rigamarole of clearing cache, rotating the display, restarting the app, restarting my iPad, etc. Nothing changed.

I tried to debug with web inspector on my Mac with my iPad plugged into the computer. Oddly enough, when I would select a specific element and un-check a CSS attribute, the page would reset, the attribute I unchecked would re-check, and the page would display correctly.

Let me know if you need more info, or if this is even the right place to ask this. I've submitted a feedback report to Apple, but other than that, I'm unsure of how I can fix this when I can't even isolate the problem without the page resetting and then displaying correctly.

[Example of page with web inspector open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj04X.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.